# Docker container to NAS Storage

Tags: docker, containers, storage

I'm trying to mount the storage volume to inside the container. like the linux i given the below command

```
**mount 10.#.##.###:/nvol1 /tmp**
```

this gives "Access denied" error, i have added the Container and host IP to storage to allow the traffic from the Container & the host server.  But i cannot mount the storage volume in the container ? Am i missing something ? i'm using Centos Operating System.

Edit Note: I have already mount the storage to the Docker host successfully and made the communication between the host file system and the container. however this new test case seeking **directly mount the storage volume on the container** not on the Docker host.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to run a mount command from inside of the container without disabling some of the isolation that docker provides (otherwise an untrusted app could mount the host root filesystem and escape). Docker prevents this by removing various capabilities from the root user inside the container.

For an NFS mount, you would typically mount this as a volume into the container in one of two ways:

1. Mount the NFS directory on the host, and map the host directory into the container. This allows you to manage the volume directly on the host in addition to inside the container.
2. Mount the NFS directory as a volume directly into the container.

For option 2, you can define the volume with something like:

```
$ docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt o=addr=10.1.23.123,rw \
    --opt device=:/nvol1 \
    nvol1

$ docker run -v nvol1:/tmp your_image
```

---

Edit: to skip the `docker volume create` step, you can do this from a run command with the `--mount` option:

```
$ docker run -it --rm \
  --mount type=volume,dst=/container/path,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,volume-opt=o=addr=192.168.1.1,volume-opt=device=:/host/path \
  foo
```

Comment: After Add the given format in Docker file it throws an error while build bash-4.2# docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 39.42 kB
Step 1 : DOCKER
Unknown instruction: DOCKER

bash-4.2# more Dockerfile
docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=nfs \
    --opt o=addr=10.#.###.###:/xbbl7nvol1,rw \
    --opt device=:/tmp \
    nvol1

Comment: Those are shell commands, not entries for a Dockerfile. You won't be able to do this at build time. Please update your question with exactly what you are trying to do, commands you are running, and files you are using.

Comment: @Satte You say several times in your question that you are trying to mount the volume into your container, which the above answer describes. However your comment asks how to do this at build time in your Dockerfile to update your image. Please update your question with exactly what commands you are running and files you are using. See [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i assume the answer you provided can be list by below points
1. Create the volume on the docker host
2. Mount the volume to the storage
3. Mount the folder inside the container

What I'm trying is
1. Directly mount the storage on the container with out mounting on the host. 
Reason: because if my container move from one host to another host the mount won't work. Hope you got my question

Comment: There are different ways to do this, but they depend on how you are running your container. Without the commands you are running and files you are using I cannot provide any more help.